# EFI to Legacy boot

Tags: boot

I have requirement switch from UEFI to legacy boot mode.

Now my 16.04 VM is not booting on legacy non UEFI virtual server.

I need to fix the boot. I have booted VM to Ubuntu desktop from CD and now running Boot Repair app.

I tried to use Recommended Settings in Boot Repair app to fix the boot and got error something like: Current session is in legacy mode. boot usb in uefi mode.

Which advanced options do I need to select in order to fix this and boot vm from Legacy boot mode?

p.s. noticed that MBR section is grayed out in Boot Repair.

Thanks
N

Comment: If the system disk is partitioned using the GPT scheme then you most likely cannot boot it in legacy mode, because the BIOS requires MBR partitioned disks. Ubuntu has nothing to do with it, the limitation is at much lower level.

Comment: BIOS does not require MBR. I started using gpt with my BIOS systems in 2010. But you have to have a bios_grub partition which is 1 or 2 MB unformatted with bios_grub flag if using gparted. Or code ef02 if using gdisk. Then you need to install the BIOS boot version of grub - grub-pc, I think if you boot Boot-Repair in BIOS mode it may offer to do that.

Comment: GParted shows
/dev/sda1 - fat32 - boot,esp (flags);
/dev/sda2 - ext2 - (no flags);
/dev/sda3 - lvm2 pv - lvm (flag);
unallocated - unallocated - 1bm of size;
Should I
1. unflag sda1?
2. create unformatted from unallocated?
3. flag it with bios_grub?
4. boot Boot-Repair in BIOS mode?

If yes, question how to boot Boot-Repair in BIOS mode? Thanks